# GCM Notification to redirect on activity not worked

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Try so many solution in my application but till not worked clicked on notification to redirect on another activity.Please give me proper solution for that, because i tried so many solution, i also try export=true, and single top. My code attach on this link, please find and give me solution

=> https://www.dropbox.com/sh/vguv249ame7zid0/AABDaqjdkMEsFmPagxH3F8U4a?dl=0

```
   Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, RedirectToLeaderboard.class);
   resultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        Random r = new Random();
        notifyID = r.nextInt(30000 - 1) + 1;
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, notifyID, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder;
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.notification_all_icon).setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.mipmap.notification_all_icon));
        // Set pending intent
        mNotifyBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(notifyID, mNotifyBuilder.build());
```

Comment: which kind of class it is where you are creating this notification , is it an activity

Comment: GCMNotificationIntentService extends GcmListenerService{}

Comment: is this function or code is getting called ? , put one log or toast to verify it

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>     PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, notifyID, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
>     PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
> ```

Replace it with

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YourActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), REQUEST_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

Comment: have you called mNotifyBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);?

Comment: make a gist.github.com and post a link

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/vguv249ame7zid0/AABDaqjdkMEsFmPagxH3F8U4a?dl=0

Comment: can you check my link ?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check [handling compatibility](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Compatibility) on [notifications](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) wherein it was mentioned that:

> Not all notification features are available for a particular version, even though the methods to set them are in the support library class [NotificationCompat.Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html).
>
> To ensure the best compatibility, create notifications with `NotificationCompat` and its subclasses, particularly `NotificationCompat.Builder`. In addition, follow this process when you implement a notification:
>
> 1. Provide all of the notification's functionality to all users, regardless of the version they're using. To do this, verify that all of the functionality is available from an [`Activity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) in your app. You may want to add a new [`Activity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) to do this.
> 2. Ensure that all users can get to the functionality in the Activity, by having it start when users click the notification. To do this, create a `PendingIntent` for the `Activity`. Call `setContentIntent()` to add the `PendingIntent` to the notification.
> 3. Now add the expanded notification features you want to use to the notification. Remember that any functionality you add also has to be available in the `Activity` that starts when users click the notification.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

My code is perfect, i got my solution..

```
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, RedirectToLeaderboard.class);
    resultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    Random r = new Random();
    notifyID = r.nextInt(30000 - 1) + 1;
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, notifyID, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder;
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.notification_all_icon).setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.mipmap.notification_all_icon));
    // Set pending intent
    mNotifyBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(notifyID, mNotifyBuilder.build());
```

Comment: you can implemen tthis code, easily redirect to launcher activity